# Calculating Running Total with OVER Clause and PARTITION BY Clause with counter

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, window-functions

how to calculate the sum of points each week_number and user_name using a counter ?
I use `sum() OVER (PARTITION BY  ORDER BY )`

And I would like to have the maximum sum at 10.
How can I do this?

Here is my original table:

[image]

Here is the result I would like to obtain:

[image]

Here is the sql code:

```
SELECT week_number,
user_name,
sum(points) OVER (PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY week_number) AS total_prime
FROM team;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
  week_number, 
  user_name, 
  points, 
  case when total_prime > 10 then 10 else total_prime end as sum, 
  case when total_prime > 1 and total_prime < 10 then null 
       when total_prime > 10 then total_prime - 10 end as dif
from
  (select 
     week_number, 
     user_name, points, 
     sum(points) over (partition by user_name order by week_number) as total_prime 
   from 
     team) a
```

I don't get it in your second table where `alan` have `point 4` but have `sum 2`.